# How to use a single actionButton to generate a tableOutput and toggling it without reloading it each time?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shinyjs

I am working on a shiny app. I need the user to input a file, and then a table is obtained from that file.

I need to have a single button that does this:

- if the input is null, nothing
- if the input is not null, generate the table and display it
- if the table is already displayed, hide it.

I have tried putting the table output as `hidden` and toggle it when the button is clicked. It works, but when I press the button again to hide the table, the table is reloaded.

I have this in my UI:

```
actionButton(inputId = "viewFile", label = "View file"),
hidden(tableOutput("fileTable"))
```

And here is what I've tried on my server:

```
  observeEvent(input$viewFile,{
      output$fileTable <- renderTable({...)}) #generating the table
      toggle("fileTable")
  })
```

As you can understand, when the `viewFile` button is clicked, the `fileTable`  output is rendered, and then it is toggled (it's not *hidden* anymore, so it's shown). To generate the output for the first time, it's perfect.

However, if I click again on the button to hide the table, the `renderTable` is calculated again. It's an useless operation (you don't want to generate a table output just to hide it).

Is there any way to keep the toggle working, but prevent the regeneration of the tableOutput? I thought about using an `if` on the output, but you can't assess output items from the server.

(`Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.`)

---

One last detail: later, I will try to improve my app by re-generating the table output if the file has changed, is there a way to do this too?

Thank you and sorry for the beginner question. I'm a bit lost. If you have any questions regarding my code, please don't hesitate.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. If you want to use `viewFile` only for toggling the state then why don't you just move `renderTable` outside the `observeEvent`?

Comment: That's exactly what I did! I had the idea just after I answered you. That's solved :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way to do exactly what I want.

I simply generate the table at the moment I load the data, and then with my button, I only toggle it.

UI:

```
file <- fileInput(inputId = "file", label="myfile")
hidden(actionButton(inputId = "viewFile", label = "View file"))
hidden(tableOutput("fileTable"))
```

Server:

```
observeEvent(input$file, {
    #The output is generated but not displayed
    output$fileTable<- renderTable({read.csv(file[4][[1]])})
    #We display the button
    toggle("viewFile")
})


observeEvent(input$viewFile,{
    toggle("fileTable")
})
```

This is what happens:

- User loads the file
- Table is generated from the file but not displayed
- Button "View file" appears
- User clicks on the button
- Table is displayed
- User clicks on the button again
- Table is hidden

Repeat ad infinitum.
Have a great day